# how to make a query that will get all products with its comments

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables; one for products and the other for products comments. I need a query that can bring me all the products with their comments connected without duplicate results from the products table.

The problem is that when I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `food_products` 
    INNER JOIN `comment`
    ON food_products.product_id = comment.product_id
```

It returns duplicates from the product table rows.

Comment: how you suppose it will not duplicate rows? If you have 2 comments for product_id = 1 you'll have a two rows in result where product_it will be equal 1. Try to imagine what result you want to get, and you'll see it

Comment: what duplicates? u mean same product with same comment?

Comment: Please put an example with two products and some comments and then show us how do you want to look the result.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to concatenate the comments together.  Try this:

```
select fp.*,
       group_concat(coalesce(c.comment) seperator '!!!')
from food_products fp left outer join
     comments c
     on fp.product_id = comment.product_id
group by fp.product_id
```

This separates the comments with a "!!!".  You can choose any separator you want; the default is a comma.